# Adding an id to an infowindow (google maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a map with infowindows. In my code, I open infowindows and I want to add events, like divs, on this infowindows.

What I would like to now it's if it is possible to add an id to an infowindow (`google.maps.InfoWindow({});`) with javascript google's maps api 3.

I declare the infowindows like this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
infowindow.setContent(
   '<p>TEST Stack overflow</p>'
   );
```

Comment: You can't modify an infowindow. It's inside an iFrame and so separate from your code.

Comment: No, depending on how you are using them it is possible to find the info window that corresponds to a marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add an id to the tags which you are creating and then access them that way?

Look at the google example which references a string.

Google shows an example of the way in which they declare [info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)